# error in link facebook with android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

i get an error when i want to link my android app to facebook api my app is aim to get a photo from camera and then share this photo via my facebook account i have use the latest facebook api i think the error in splashFragment i think it don't find it and this my code

***Xml File***

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_name"
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:lines="2"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:text="Get Starting"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/op_cam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Open Camera" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/login_button" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:text="Share"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.facebook.scrumptious.SelectionFragment"
          android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.facebook.scrumptious.SplashFragment"
          android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

***and this the code***

```
package work.islam;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;

import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FaceBook_Activity_sharing extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int SPLASH = 0;
    private static final int SELECTION = 1;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SELECTION +1;



    private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(arg0);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
        fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                transaction.show(fragments[i]);
            } else {
                transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private boolean isResumed = false;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // Only make changes if the activity is visible
        if (isResumed) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            // Get the number of entries in the back stack
            int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            // Clear the back stack
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
                manager.popBackStack();
            }
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                // If the session state is open:
                // Show the authenticated fragment
                showFragment(SELECTION, false);
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                // If the session state is closed:
                // Show the login fragment
                showFragment(SPLASH, false);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // if the session is already open,
            // try to show the selection fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else {
            // otherwise present the splash screen
            // and ask the person to login.
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
        new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, 
                SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };


}
```

also i tried to connect facebook only with android but i failed 
i want to edit this code or just to connect facebook with android

***this is the error i get***

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
activity_dash_board cannot be resolved or is not a field    TestfacebookstackoverflowActivity.java  /testfacebookstackoverflow/src/islam/work/com   line 33 Java Problem
AppEngineDriver cannot be resolved to a type    DemoEntityManagerSqlFactory.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/sql   line 45 Java Problem
AppEngineFile cannot be resolved to a type  PhotoServiceManager.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 156    Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    DownloadServlet.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 42 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    Photo.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model   line 26 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    Photo.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model   line 28 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoManagerSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/sql   line 233    Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 48 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 49 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 53 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoServiceManager.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 56 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoServiceManager.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 71 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoServiceManager.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 155    Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/sql   line 27 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/sql   line 58 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/sql   line 59 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/sql   line 63 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    PhotoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/sql   line 64 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    UploadHandlerServlet.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 47 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    UploadHandlerServlet.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 48 Java Problem
BlobKey cannot be resolved to a type    UploadHandlerServlet.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 64 Java Problem
BlobstoreService cannot be resolved to a type   DownloadServlet.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 43 Java Problem
BlobstoreService cannot be resolved to a type   PhotoServiceManager.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 51 Java Problem
BlobstoreService cannot be resolved to a type   PhotoServiceManager.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 160    Java Problem
BlobstoreService cannot be resolved to a type   UploadHandlerServlet.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 46 Java Problem
BlobstoreServiceFactory cannot be resolved  DownloadServlet.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 43 Java Problem
BlobstoreServiceFactory cannot be resolved  PhotoServiceManager.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 51 Java Problem
BlobstoreServiceFactory cannot be resolved  PhotoServiceManager.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 160    Java Problem
BlobstoreServiceFactory cannot be resolved  UploadHandlerServlet.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo line 46 Java Problem
CompositeFilterOperator cannot be resolved to a variable    CommentManagerNoSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 61 Java Problem
CompositeFilterOperator cannot be resolved to a variable    PhotoManagerNoSql.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 99 Java Problem
DashBoard cannot be resolved to a type  TestfacebookstackoverflowActivity.java  /testfacebookstackoverflow/src/islam/work/com   line 79 Java Problem
DatastoreService cannot be resolved to a type   DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 59 Java Problem
DatastoreService cannot be resolved to a type   DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 81 Java Problem
DatastoreService cannot be resolved to a type   DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 113    Java Problem
DatastoreService cannot be resolved to a type   DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 128    Java Problem
DatastoreService cannot be resolved to a type   DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 195    Java Problem
DatastoreService cannot be resolved to a type   PhotoManagerNoSql.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 133    Java Problem
DialogError cannot be resolved to a type    FaceBookSharingPhotoActivity.java   /FaceBookSharingPhoto/src/work/islam    line 197    Java Problem
DialogListener cannot be resolved to a type FaceBookSharingPhotoActivity.java   /FaceBookSharingPhoto/src/work/islam    line 189    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentManagerNoSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 95 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 33 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 47 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 52 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 57 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 63 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 68 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 74 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 79 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 84 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 89 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 94 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 99 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type CommentNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 104    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 83 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 114    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 128    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 146    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 150    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 197    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 221    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityNoSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 26 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityNoSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 28 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityNoSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 29 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityNoSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 33 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityNoSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 33 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityNoSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 37 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityNoSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 37 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityNoSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 40 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoEntityNoSql.java    /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 41 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoUserManagerNoSql.java   /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 45 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoUserNoSql.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 28 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoUserNoSql.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 38 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoUserNoSql.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 43 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoUserNoSql.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 48 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoUserNoSql.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 53 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type DemoUserNoSql.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 58 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoManagerNoSql.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 126    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoManagerNoSql.java  /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 136    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 37 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 44 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 49 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 54 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 59 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 65 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 70 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 75 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 80 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 85 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 90 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 95 Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 100    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 105    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 110    Java Problem
Entity cannot be resolved to a type PhotoNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 117    Java Problem
EntityNotFoundException cannot be resolved to a type    DemoEntityManagerNoSql.java /PhotoSharingDemo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/model/nosql line 131    Java Problem
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent').  main.xml    /testfacebookstackoverflow/res/layout   line 9  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent').  main.xml    /testfacebookstackoverflow/res/layout   line 15 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').   main.xml    /testfacebookstackoverflow/res/layout   line 9  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').   main.xml    /testfacebookstackoverflow/res/layout   line 15 Android AAPT Problem
```

Comment: what do you mean with logcat????

Comment: logcat shows errors occurs in your code you can this window in your eclipse,

Comment: any answeeeeeeeeeeer plz????